# How to get the first different range of two string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have two string like below:

```
NSString *path1 = @"/Users/user/Desktop/AAA/BBB/1.txt";
NSString *path2 = @"/Users/user/Document/test/AAA/CCC/2.txt";
```

Right now i want to get the first different string for the two string: "Desktop" for path1 and "Document/test" for path2. And how about if there are more than 2 NSString
Is there any algorithm to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
-(NSString *)findDiferentIn:(NSArray *)first By:(NSArray *)second{

    for (int i = 0; i < [first count]; i++) {
        if (![second objectAtIndex:i]) {
            return [first objectAtIndex:i];
        }else{
            if (![[first objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[second objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                return [first objectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
    }

    return @"";
}
```

use:

```
NSString *path1 = @"/Users/user/Desktop/AAA/BBB/1.txt";
NSString *path2 = @"/Users/user/Document/test/AAA/CCC/2.txt";

NSLog(@"diferent in first string: %@", [self findDiferentIn:[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] By:[path2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]]);
NSLog(@"diferent in second string: %@", [self findDiferentIn:[path2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] By:[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]]);
```